# setting cq:tags and ajax call together in page properties: Loosing textfield data on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, aem, aem-6

I have a scenario where, in AEM page properties. On click of a button in Page properties:
(1). I need get cq:tags and automatically set into a page properties - for this I need a page reload,
(2). also, in the same call I am getting the response from ajax call to be shown into a textfield.

to get point (1) from above, I need to reload the page. 
but as soon as I try to do so using `window.location.reload();` , I loose that data(from ajax call at point (2)) which is setting in the text field(DOM element).

And when if I don't call window.location.reload();, my cq:tags are not set.

$.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : '/abc/def/ijk.json',
            data : {
                pagePath : pagePathURL
            },
            success : function(data) {

```
            if (data != "" || data != undefined) {
                var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
                if (jsonObj != undefined && jsonObj.Success == true) {
                         // tried here 

                        if (jsonObj.PageTitle != undefined) {
                        var pageTitle = jsonObj.PageTitle;

                        $('.some-text').val(pageTitle);
                    }
```

What have I tried so far:

```
// after  jsonObj.Success == true
window.location.reload();                    
setTimeout(console.log(data),4000000);
```

How can I do both together ?

Answer (score 0):

You have conflicting requirements. You can't keep form data when also refreshing the page. Websites don't work that way. You have to post the data - the `cq:tags` as well the text for the text field - to the corresponding nodes. Which are basically just AJAX requests in the background. You could also show notifications indicating what data was automatically saved.

Then, you can refresh the page (which might be optional at this point, as the data is persisted).

If that does not match your requirements, save the form data in the local storage and read it, if necessary.